# PHP button with jQuery and POST to return value

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

I have simple form to get username and want to achieve that:

- when user click button it gets disabled to prevent multiple clicks (it may take few seconds to process all data in real scenario as calling APIs, writing to DB, etc);
- after click new POST request needs to happen in order to capture $_POST['username'] in PHP and process the request further.

How to achieve that?

The code is like that but does not work as expected:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
        $uname=$_POST['username'];
        header('Location: success.php');
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Form</title>
  </head>
<body>

<form id="your_form_id" action="test4.php" method="post">
     <p><label>Username</label>
     <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value=""  autofocus/></p>
     <input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit-button").on("click", function(e){
        document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById("submit-button").value="Processing, please wait...";
        document.getElementById("your_form_id").submit();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {` There is no element with that `name`, it'll never trigger.

Comment: Also maybe take a look at [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: It's not the cause of the issue, but as an aside: any particular reason for the ancient version of jquery? In fact, any particular reason for jquery at all? If all its doing is handling a submit event that is trivial to do with native JS

Comment: "_PHP button with Java and POST..._" Java is _not_ Javascript

Comment: And even if the name in `if(isset($_POST['submit-button']))` was fixed, it would still never trigger - a) you _disabled_ the submit button, and b) your form does not really get submitted by clicking the button here, but you are submitting it by calling its `submit` method. Both of those things prevent the submit button to become part of the submitted data set in the first place.

Comment: Why does this mention the use of Java in the title when the post is not even relevant to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that the following principle can be used:

- test-a.php (ordinary html form with jQuery and AJAX included to disable submit button and show simple 'page loader');
- test-b.php (to process data with PHP);
- test-c.php (to show the response).

**test-a.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax example with Page loader</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /*CSS for Page loader*/
        #loader {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // stops the default action of an element from happening
                $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true); // disable button with id=submitButton
                $('#loader').show(); // show "Page loader"

                // send AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test-b.php', //path to process PHP file
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        // save response to session variable
                        sessionStorage.setItem('response', response);
                        // forward to "test-c.php"
                        window.location.href = 'test-c.php';
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required><br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required><br>

        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <div id="loader">
        This is page loader, please wait...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**test-b.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Here you can use $name and $email for further processing or to save into database

// Example of printing response data
$response = "The following data has been received:<br>";
$response .= "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
$response .= "Email: " . $email . "<br>";

// save response to session variable
$_SESSION['response'] = $response;

// we finish work in this file
exit;
?>
```

**test-c.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Success</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Process file response:</h1>
    <?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['response'])) {
        $response = $_SESSION['response'];
        echo $response;
        unset($_SESSION['response']); // unset session variable
    } else {
        echo "No data to show.";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code shows how to read values on POST with PHP in case JavaScript is used with onclick submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JQuery library but you are using native JavaScript commands to process the button and the submit(). Either you do everything in Pure JS, or you do everything in JQuery.
The code below uses only JQuery. Moreover I replaced the submit by a button.
.
And finally the buttons are not passed in POST, so if you have to do a test do it on the input field.

Below is a code that includes the elements that I have just mentioned and that should help you.

```
<?
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $uname=$_POST['username'];
        header('Location: success.php');
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Form</title>
  </head>
<body>

<form id="your_form_id" action="test4.php" method="post">
     <p><label>Username</label>
     <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value=""  autofocus/></p>
     <input type="button" id="submit-button" name="submit-button" value="Login" />
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit-button").on("click", function(e){
            $('#submit-button').prop('disabled',true);
            $('#submit-button').val('Processing, please wait...');
            $('#your_form_id').submit();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx for your solution. If I put die($uname); below $uname=$_POST['username']; it does not return $uname value. How to achieve that?

Comment: @TaKo If the solution provided has helped you, you can vote for it (so that it may also help other people). And if not why do you want to make a god...? If you want to see what your field or any field contains you can use `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)`. And in your case comment out the `header` function